# Asynchronously place data into a dynamically produced div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, asynchronous

I have a link that sends a query string to a PHP file that returns data from a Mysql server as JSON. I want to put this JSON data into a DIV that has an ID which matches the query string sent to the PHP file.

Here is my PHP generated Link and DIV

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>BadNoise</title> 



</head> 
<body> 



    <form action="Artisttest.php" method="post"> 
        <fieldset> 
            <p> <input type="submit" value=" Search Our Artists" /> </p> 
        </fieldset> 
    </form> 

    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","ee2800","secret","ee2800");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM artist LIMIT 10");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

echo " <h2>List of BadNoise Artists</h2>
    <table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Artist Number</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Search Songs</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td> <a class="dynamic" href="test4.php?name='. urlencode($row['ArtistNumber']).'">Search Songs</a></td>';
  echo "<td><div id=" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "></div></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

$results->close();
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="general.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Here is the PHP file that returns the JSON data

```
<?php

$row = $_GET['name'];
echo $_GET['name'];

$dbs = new mysqli("localhost", "ee2800", "secret", "ee2800");

$results = $dbs->query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE ArtistNumber = {$_GET['name']};");

$rows = array();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
{
    $rows[] = $r;
}

  echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

And here is my attempt at doing this asynchronously with JS.

```
$(function() {
    $("a.dynamic").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var destDiv = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').last().find('div[id]');
       $.getJSON( this.href, function(obj){
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
               destDiv.append("<p>"+value.Title+"</p>");
            });
       });
    });
});
```

I think I am on the right path but am having trouble targeting the DIV.

Is this what you meant?

```
</tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Steve</td><td>Perry</td><td> <a id="dynamic" href="test4.php?name=1">Search Songs</a></td></tr><td><div id=1></div></td>
```

Comment: You need a properly addressed id name here and not just a `#` in this '$("#").append("<p>"+value.Title+"</p>");'

Comment: u r using <a id="dynamic" in the loop, so all the anchors will have same id, use a class instead

Comment: I left the # as I don't know how to target the div.

Comment: how would I give each a different class? as i need the data to load in the correct div

Comment: -1 Why are you closing the `tr` prematurely?

Comment: Don't forget to checkmark the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're adding the content on the same row where the click originated, you may not need the `id` of the div in order to add the content there. Using the link that was clicked determine the parent `tr` using `.closest()` the drill down to the div using `.find()` and `.last()`.

And since you're likely to have multiple links I would recommend using a class `.dynamic` instead of an id. `<td> <a class="dynamic" href="test4 ....`

This should do it:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.dynamic").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var destDiv = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').last().find('div[id]');
       $.getJSON( this.href, function(obj){
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
               destDiv.append("<p>"+value.Title+"</p>");
            });
       });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

The above code has been edited to include `DOM ready`.

[Concept verification](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/dbq8woss/1/) --> with `DOM ready` clicking a `a.dynamic` link does not navigate to the link.

Comment: this didn't seem to work, the page still goes to the php page.

Comment: The js does not prevent the the href loading..test4.php still loads

Comment: Something else must be causing that. Do you have this code in DOM ready? Can you post a sample row (actual HTML)?

Comment: I have already included DOM ready in my answer. If you have additional code to include, please add it in the question; it extremely difficult to read code in the comments.

Comment: i have added a row to the question

Comment: Please take a look at the `demo` I have included in my answer. There are two changes you need to make: (1) use **class="dynamic"** instead of **id=dynamic**. (2) you need to close the `tr`s at the end of the `td` with the `div`.

Comment: sorry i don't know what that verifies. the result is just the html that i gave you. what i want is for when the "search songs" link is clicked, the json from test4.php to be placed in the div with id of 1...

Comment: Verifies: *this didn't seem to work, the page still goes to the php page.* and *The js does not prevent the the href loading..test4.php still loads* **If you have any errors or specific questions with the code I provided, please let us know.**

Comment: ok sorry i thought you were giving a solution. I have implemented the changes you suggest, but i still seem to be getting the same result. I have changed the question to reflect your changes

Comment: What I have provided is a solution. *Same result* is not very descriptive. Can you provide a link to your page?

Comment: sorry, same result as in test4.php still loads. which is not what I wanted, i wanted the data from test4.php to load asynchronously. Im afraid I'm running it on my local server. unless there is a quick way to get in online?

Comment: I don't know how to further help you -- I am willing to but ... There's definitely something wrong. If you know how ajax works, then you would know that my jsfiddle and your current page are miles apart. My demo tries to load the page via ajax but of course you know that does not work on jsfiddle since we do not have access to there server to place any content there. And we can tell that it does prevent the clicks from navigating to the pages. Clearly your's is navigating to the page requested. **Something is different and without seeing your page I can't tell what it is :(**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59900/discussion-between-user3558931-and-user3075549).